# Type narrowing lost in subsequent Array.prototype.map

Tags: typescript

Can anyone help explain the following type checking errors:

```
interface Foo {
    kind: 'foo';
    a: string;
}

interface Bar {
    kind: 'bar';
    b: number;
}

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

interface Container {
    ids: number[];
    fooBar: FooBar;
}

const cont: Container = {
    ids: [1, 2],
    fooBar: { kind: 'foo', a: 'a' },
};

switch (cont.fooBar.kind) {
    case 'foo':
        console.log(cont.fooBar.a); // OK

        cont.ids.map((id) => {
            console.log(`${id} - ${cont.fooBar.a}`);
            // Property 'a' does not exist on type FooBar
            //   Property 'a' does not exist on type Bar
        })
        break;
    case 'bar':
        console.log(cont.fooBar.b); // OK

        cont.ids.map((id) => {
            console.log(`${id} - ${cont.fooBar.b}`);
            // Property 'b' does not exist on type FooBar
            //   Property 'b' does not exist on type Foo
        })
        break;
}
```

[Live example on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIDWoAJgFzIDkMmVA3PoXJQM5hSgDmjAvrrlCRYiFACE4UHEwIkQFagCNJDGckWUQAVwC2i6HwFgAngAcUGdBKkBeNJmQAfZNcaDw0eEmQBhdODhQaGlCZGBSVk1dfSgAbQBdRlDaK0lKS1dcflwEf3ZkXPBKPwCg2xDCcMjkWIBGABpkACZ4+rUU60psYjJKGjpGlmo4KmReNt43VgB3YDAEAAtkAApCsAA6Dsl1uVIASgqCBDhWFH70KnI1UMLWdAAbCHX79C5V-w2tqHW4PfpkAD0AOQAHkANICUI3D7rKrrHRwUzLZbhA42AB8hyh0JAd0ez1eywABgASbDhXjIAC0yDJa02mGsP14RL+12xgOBAAUoOhzFATMNRqR0BBWMgQOgwMgIAAPYD5fzIEzmeypKDs7FAwg8vnQQVUEbIEViiVSmXyxUgZVmcSSTVjPYOxRQCBwIhJQjHU5KFRXDkFPIPJ4vN70r7rRR-TmgiEO+lwhFIlH7ZAYrEB27BglvUnk0iUml0mERxQstkB0La3X8g2KYWi8WS6VyhXSpUqiyM+2Vwjagg1-XGJQN03Ni1t5Ad21qh28J0Bl1uj1ZIA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by grabbing `fooBar` to a local `const`, and using `fooBar` rather than `cont.fooBar` in the `switch`:

```
const { fooBar } = cont; // <====
switch (fooBar.kind) {
    case 'foo':
        console.log(fooBar.a); // OK

        cont.ids.map((id) => {
            console.log(`${id} - ${fooBar.a}`); // OK now
        })
        break;
    case 'bar':
        console.log(fooBar.b); // OK

        cont.ids.map((id) => {
            console.log(`${id} - ${fooBar.b}`); // OK now
        })
        break;
}
```

[Live copy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIDWoAJgFzIDkMmVA3PoXJQM5hSgDmjAvrrlCRYiFACE4UHEwIkQFagCNJDGckWUQAVwC2i6HwFgAngAcUGdBKkBeNJmQAfZNcaDw0eEmQBhdODhQaGlCZGBSVk1dfSgAbQBdRlDaK0lKS1dcflwEf3ZkXPBKPwCg2xDCcMjkWIBGABpkACZ4+rUU60psYjJKGjpGlmo4KmReNt43Qvzujskx5DtCsEZWAHdgMAQAC2QACjmoADo5UgBKCoIEOFYUfvQqcjVQ6fQAGwgjt-QuA8xrI5wM70ZAAelByAA8gBpAShF7+MBHKpHHRwUx7PbhC42AB8l3hCJArHen2+vwABgASbDhXjIAC0yBph0BvApwLBEJhyBA6DWz0IvDOgoIiigEDgRCShGutyUKiehKueVJXx+f1Sx0UnPBUNhooKiOREVR6Mx2MW+Lwyvhrw+6spNLpjOZ2FZinZuu50N5-MNwsN4sl0qyQA)

Originally I did that in each `case`, but TypeScript is happy with it as above as well.

I *think* it's because TypeScript can't know for sure that the callback is synchronous, and since `cont.fooBar` may be changed by other code later if the callback is asynchronous, it can't be sure the narrowed type is still correct. Grabbing it local removes that doubt. That theory is supported by the fact that if you make it `let { fooBar } = cont;` instead of `const { fooBar } = cont;`, it fails to keep the narrowed type again.